# Why does my argument appears to be over written with a vhost.exe

Tags: c#

I have a simple file moving program that takes a single parameter for which directory to watch. In my program the parameter is passed as a string:

```
"C:\Projects\Utilities\"
```

however when I inspect

```
string[] cmdargs = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

after it is passed in, the only value in cmdargs is:

```
"C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\SshClient\\SshClient\\bin\\Debug\\SshClient.exe"
```

SshClient.exe is the name of this program. The value it is seeing cannot be found in the program. Can someone explain how this may be happening?

This is a console application, .net 4.5.2 and uses the Renci.SshNet library

Thanks

Comment: Where are you passing in the parameter?

Comment: It is simply telling you that you did not pass a command line argument.  Standard when you debug, be sure to use Project > Properties > Debug > "Command line arguments" box.

Comment: I am using the Project > Properties > Debug > "Command line arguments" box, that is where it is passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the GetCommandLineArgs docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> An array of string where each element contains a command-line argument. The first element is the executable file name, and the following zero or more elements contain the remaining command-line arguments.

Comment: The link I posted is for .NET 4.7.2, but the information is the same for 4.5.2.

Comment: this explains it. The weird thing is I've been doing passing the parameter the same for months, it just began writing the exe over yesterday. Thank you!